# What does '-' mean in the job's URL?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

What does the symbol '-' mean in the job's URL https://mygitlab.com/mynamespace/myproject/-/jobs/827991 (Gitlab CI)? Is it normal, "valid" URL? I plan to store it in a database and to use it as an URI to the job, so will I have any problems with this URL? How "stable" is it? Is it possible that something is missing (some project property/attribute), so there is this '-' but if somebody will add this attribute to the project then the URL will be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following, you or your company have decided to do a major rebranding, and part of this migration is abandoning old domain name for a new one. With that in mind you can see that you'll have to update all of the records with a new domain name. Same is true if you want to migrate your project to a different namespace, or just rename a project. There are stable and unique fields though:

- project id
- job id

Using these fields you can always construct a valid url, no matter what happened to human-readable parts of that url.

Look at jobs api: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#get-a-single-job

You can get an url you mentioned earlier from "web_url" attribute of response

```
"web_url": "https://example.com/foo/bar/-/jobs/8"
```

By storing only 2 integers and global gitlab url you will always get a proper "human-readable" url no matter what.